# $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+h \hat{u})-f(x)}{h}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}u_x+ \cdot \cdot \cdot$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

How are the following directional derivative definitions equivalent: $$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+h \hat{u})-f(x)}{h}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}u_x+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}u_y+\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}u_z+ \cdot \cdot \cdot$$

where $u_i$ are unit vectors.

as given here:
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirectionalDerivative.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not a definition ! If $f$ is differentiable at $x$, then the directional derivative is given by

$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+h \hat{u})-f(x)}{h}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x)u_x+ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x)u_y+\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(x)u_z$

where $\hat{u}=(u_x,u_y,u_z)$

Comment: And why are those two equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

consider $f(\mathbf{x}+h\hat{\mathbf{u}})$ as a function of $h$ (with fixed $\mathbf{x}$ and $\hat{\mathbf{u}})$  and evaluate the derivative
$$
\frac{df}{dh}
$$
at $h=0$ using the chain rule.